# SQLite - Store a list of files in a single table cell

Tags: java, database, list, sqlite, file

I'm making a Java web application where users can upload multiple text documents and I'm wondering about the best way use a database to display a particular user's uploaded documents.

So far, I've thought of a few ways, but none seem like a good solution.

Solution 1:

Keep an 'uploads' table alongside the 'users' table and then query it with something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE USER_ID = "+id+";".
```

Solution 2:

Add an uploads column to my 'users' table and store all the user's uploads as a string that I can crudely parse as a list:

```
"SELECT uploads FROM users WHERE USER_ID = "+id+";"
```

could return a string: "upload1.txt,upload2.txt,upload3.txt"

Solution 3:

Skip the database entirely for the uploaded files and prepend USER_ID to the front of the file name:

```
"<some user id>_upload1.txt"
```

It seems all three of these have pretty substantial drawbacks, so I'm pretty sure none of them are correct. I've only been teaching myself about databases for the past few days, so I'm sure there is a preferred way of doing it that I don't know about yet, but I can't figure out what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is best in my eyes. Good normalization and flexibility.